# live audio streaming in android

Tags: android

I am facing problem to play a audio url using MediaPlayer as well as native Android audio player.
Here is my url
http://live.politiafm.com:8500/politiafm.mp3

Here is my code 
Using native audio player
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(STREAM_URL), "audio/*");
        StartActivity(intent);
Using Media Player
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.create(Landing.this, Uri.parse(STREAM_URL));

```
    mp.prepareAsync();
    mp.start();
```

In both the cases audio is not playing. Can some body help me out from this trouble.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is to late a reply but in case if you are still facing the same problem,

you need to enable mime type for your server based on the type of the server. The MIME types are something you can learn from here how to enable them for Tomcat Server, IIS Server or Apache, whichever your mp3 file is hosted on : http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapServerSetup/tutorial.asp?page=settingUpMIME

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try changing

```
mp.prepare();
```

not

```
mp.prepareAsyunc();
```